Fix labels in forest plot so they are above rather than right in the middle of bars using ggplot2
Could someone please help me with my code so that the OR labels are on top of each bar rather than right in the middle?
I was able to get the labels, but I am struggling to figure out how to adjust them.
A fix would be hugely appreciated!!!
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

# Create a data frame with your odds ratios and confidence intervals
odds_ratios <- c(1.290, 1.217, 1.231, 1.242)
ci_lower <- c(1.107, 1.038, 1.019, 1.028)
ci_upper <- c(1.504, 1.427, 1.486, 1.500)
or <- c(1.29, 1.22, 1.23, 1.24)
ci <- c("1.11 to 1.50", " 1.04 to 1.43", "1.02 to 1.49", "1.24 to 1.50")

Model <- c("Unadjusted (AUC=53.1%)", "Adjusted for family factors (AUC=63.1%)", 
           "Adjusted for family and self-functioning factors (AUC=85.0%)", 
           "Adjusted for family, self-functioning, and socio-demographic factors (AUC=85.2%)")

# Create a data frame
data <- data.frame(
  Model = Model,
  Odds_Ratio = odds_ratios,
  CI_lower = ci_lower,
  CI_upper = ci_upper,
  or <- or,
  ci <- ci

)

# Define the desired order of levels
desired_order <- c("Unadjusted (AUC=53.1%)", "Adjusted for family factors (AUC=63.1%)", 
                   "Adjusted for family and self-functioning factors (AUC=85.0%)", 
                   "Adjusted for family, self-functioning, and socio-demographic factors (AUC=85.2%)")

# Reorder the data frame rows based on the desired order
data <- data %>%
  mutate(Model = factor(Model, levels = desired_order)) %>%
  arrange(Model)

# Add a row number column
data$row_num <- 1:nrow(data)

# Define custom breaks and labels for the x-axis
custom_breaks <- c(0.5, 1, 1.2, 1.5)
custom_labels <- c(" ", "Just as likely", "1.2x as likely", "1.5x as likely")

# Add significance column
data$Significance <- ifelse(data$CI_lower > 1 | data$CI_upper < 1, "Significant", "Not Significant")

# Wrap long labels
data$Model <- factor(str_wrap(data$Model, width = 30),
                     levels = str_wrap(desired_order, width = 30))

# Create the forest plot with customized labels
ggplot(data, aes(x = Odds_Ratio, y = fct_rev(Model))) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1, linetype = "dashed", color = "gray") +
  geom_point(aes(x = Odds_Ratio, color = Significance), size = 3) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = CI_lower, xmax = CI_upper), height = 0.3) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = custom_breaks, labels = custom_labels) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Significant" = "red", "Not Significant" = "black")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x = "Odds Ratio", y = " ") +
  ggtitle(paste("Odds Ratios for Family Affectedness of Individual Chronic Pain:", "\n", "Women vs. Men")) +
  theme(
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text = element_text(size = 10),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = "gray", linetype = "dashed"),
    legend.position = "none",
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, lineheight = 1.2)
  )


Thank you so much in advance!!

You can try geom_text(aes(label = `ci....ci`), vjust = 0). Setting vjust to a (small) negative number can add some padding if you need it.

Ahh great thanks, worked like a charm!! Thanks you for your service <3 <3
